Entity Framework Core : check if comma-separated string contains any value from list
I have the following table:
recipe            

id  | ingredients     
----+--------------
 1  | "1,2,3"          
 2  | "3,4"           
 3  | "2"        
 4  | "1,2,3,4" 

I want to find all recipes containing ingredient "1", "3" or "4". How can I achieve that using Entity Framework Core?
Here's what I've tried, but it seems like this expression is not translatable:
var ingredientIds = new List<string> {"1", "3", "4"};

var recipes = dbContext.Set<Recipe>
                       .Where(x => x.IngredientIds.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None).Any(y => ingredientIds.Contains(y))
                       .ToList();


What database are you using?

I'm using postgresql.

use contains after splitting, that will help you to find the value exist or not in the columns, second approach is if you are using native Query then it will be easier
SELECT *
FROM [OneWindowPRD].[dbo].[recipe]
WHERE [ingredients] like '%1%' OR [ingredients] like '%3%' OR [ingredients] like '%4%'

That's not a good design. PostgreSQL has arrays that can be indexed and searched.  Either use a RecipeIngredients table or change the field type to int[]. That array can be mapped to an int[] or List<int> property. BUT it's infinitely better to have proper tables so you can have a Recipe.Ingredients property that's an actual List<Ingredient>

This is an old database and I cannot change the design.

var newrecipes = (from r1 in recipes
                  from i in ingredients
                  where r1.IngredientIds.Contains(i.Id.ToString())
                  select new { recipe = r1.Id, ingedientId = i.Id, ingredientName = i.Name }
                  );
foreach (var item in newrecipes )
{
System.Console.WriteLine($"recipe {item.recipe}: ingredient: {item.ingedientId}, {item.ingredientName}");
}

outputs (when using the data from you other question: Entity Framework Core : join comma-separated list ):
recipe 1: ingredient: 1, flour
recipe 1: ingredient: 2, sugar
recipe 1: ingredient: 3, egg
recipe 2: ingredient: 3, egg
recipe 2: ingredient: 4, butter
recipe 3: ingredient: 2, sugar
recipe 4: ingredient: 1, flour
recipe 4: ingredient: 2, sugar
recipe 4: ingredient: 3, egg
recipe 4: ingredient: 4, butter

EDIT: When ingredient like 100, or any ingredient with more than 1 digit, is added a small change is needed in the where part:
.Where(x => (x.r.IngredientIds+",").Contains(x.i.Id.ToString()+","))

EDIT2: (see comments, to get the difference between, for example, 21 and 121 correct):

I also added a Trim() around IngredientIds, to make sure that does not end with 1 or more spaces.

.Where(x => ("," + x.r.IngredientIds.Trim() + ",").Contains("<" + x.i.Id.ToString() + ","))

FINAL EDIT ():  Because of the feedback from Panagiotis Kanavos that it would be better to use string_split() (or an alternative with same functionality):
Doing split in LINQ is also possible, see:
var newlist2 = (from i in ingredients
               join r in recipes on 1 equals 1
               select new { r, i })
               .Where(x => x.r.IngredientIds.Replace(" ","").Split(',').Any(
                        p => p == x.i.Id.ToString()))
               .Select(x => new { recipe = x.r.Id, ingredient = x.i.Name})
               .OrderBy(x => x.recipe).ThenBy(y => y.ingredient)
               ;


Will this work if I add a new row (id: 5, ingredients: "123")?

When you make sure that the new row is in the list ingredients, then it should work.

What I mean, is that new row will be included in the results if it partially matches any id.

Please do some testing and found out....   (Sorry I do not now how an id can only partially match.....)

I mean, that if ingredientIds contains "1", it will return all recipes which include a recipe which contains 1. So also a row with ingredients: "2,3,100" will be returned, because 100 contains 1.

Ok, added some comment about that in the answer.

That's actually a nice solution, thanks!

More info: Language Integrated Query (LINQ)

No, this doesn't cut it, even with the later addition. If there's a "121" in the ingredients, then it contains ids "1,", "21," and "121,".

Indeed, but that could be fixed easily, by adding a ","at the start to.

The real fix is to use split_to_array or split_to_table in a computed property or with FromSQL. NpgSql maps several array searching operators,

@PanagiotisKanavos: I think you share an opinion when you say "The real fix is ​​to", because there has to be a reason why LINQ is being maintained. In this case doing it with LINQ can also solve the problem (and, IMHO, it might be better to .... o no, let's not say something opiniated!

@Luuk the problem is the attempt to search the string, not LINQ.  If it was an opinion there wouldn't be Split methods. You already found one problem with this answer, leading or trailing commas. What if there's already a leading comma, due to an empty first entry? As the link shows, NpgSql maps ids.Contains(id) to id @> ids, which means a correct solution would be id @> split_to_array(ids). Performance would be as bad, but at least there woudln't be mismatches. That leaves mapping split_to_array(ids) to a computed column. All of this works fine with LINQ and EF

Without splitting, another option would be to use NpgSql's regex support through EF.Functions.Like or EF.Functions.ILike. If you can come up with a regex that matches a single ID, you can use Where EF.Functions.Like(r.IngredientIds,pattern). It's easier to create a regex that correctly handles commas

@PanagiotisKanavos: I added a LINQ solution using  split.

Well, you shouldn't be using comma delimited values in the first place, that's what's causing your problem.
The solution would be to change the database design to create a proper many-to-many relationship between recipe and ingredients.
In a DB first design, you'll add an IngredientToRecipe table:
CREATE TABLE IngredientToRecipe 
(
    recepieId int NOT NULL,
    IngredientId int NOT NULL,
    CONTRAINT PrimaryKey Pk_IngredientToRecipe (recepieId, IngredientId)
)

In a Code first design, you'll have to add navigation properties to your entities as collections:
class Recipe
{
  public List<Ingredient> Ingredients {get;set;}
  // other properties here
}

class Ingredient
{
  public List<Recipe> Recipes {get;set;}
  // other properties here
}

EF Core will know how to translate this to a many-to-many relationship.

As others have said, this is a terrible design that will always result in bad performance. PostgreSQL has array types that can be indexed so the ingredient IDs could be stored as an int[] at least. Even in an old database you could create a generated column, map it to your model AND index it, improving performance.
If you can't do that, you can use NpgSql's array array or regular expression support to search for a value no matter where it appears. NpgSql maps several PostgreSQL operators and functions allowing them to be used in LINQ queries.
Split to array
PosgreSQL has array types and the string_to_array method splits a string and returns a text[] array. NpgSQL maps this to EF.Functions.StringToArray. You can use it together with array operators to find the rows that have one or all of the search ingeredients.
In NpgSql 8 and later you may be able to write
var ingredientIds = new List<string> {"1", "3", "4"};

var recipes = from recipe in ctx.Recipes
              where EF.Functions.StringToArray(recipe.IngredientIds)
                                .All(ingredientIds)
              select recipe;

NOTE: I haven't tested this. It should map to string_to_array(ingredientIds) <@ $1
To search for a single value, you can use Contains instead of All.
var recipes = from recipe in ctx.Recipes
              where EF.Functions.StringToArray(recipe.IngredientIds)
                                .Contains(someId)
              select recipe;

If you map IngredientIds to a generated column, eg  using string_to_array you'll be able to use just :
var recipes = from recipe in ctx.Recipes
              where recipe.IngredientIds.All(ingredientIds)
              select recipe;

PostgreSQL also allows creating indexes on expressions. You may be able to create an index on the string_to_array(Recipe.IngredientIds) expression to accelerate the array operation.
Regular Expressions
If that's not possible, you can use regular expressions to search for a specific ID, with ~, LIKE or the case-insensitive ILIKE operators. Check Pattern Matching  in the PostgreSql docs. ~ is mapped to Regex.IsMatch and LIKE/ILIKE are mapped to EF.Functions.Like and EF.Functions.ILike.
You may be able to use (\A|,)id(/Z|,) to find values that are either surrounded by commas or are the first or last value in the list:
var id="12";
var pattern=$@"(\A|,){id}(/Z|,)";

var recipes = from recipe in ctx.Recipes
              where Regex.IsMatch(recipe.IngredientIds,pattern)
              select recipe;

